# Can I use PixelMed on Android?

Tags: java, android

I want to develop an Android application that visualize Dicom files and present them on screen. I do not know what library that I can use.

Can I use [PixelMed](http://www.pixelmed.com/) (Java DICOM Toolkit) on Android?

Please advise me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am interested in the same thing as you, and I made a very simple test, incorporating the pixelmed.jar archive into my Android project and tried to access it. To my great satisfaction, it seems to work without problems.

I only made a very simple Hello World application where I referenced the pixelmed library, outputting the tag number for a single attribute instead of "Hello, Android":

```
tv.setText(com.pixelmed.dicom.TagFromName.CollimatorShape.toString());
```

and this works as intended.

I have not tried anything more complicated yet, I am very new to Android development, but anyway this is a satisfactory start.

One thing to note: when developing in Eclipse, I needed to allocate more memory for the IDE in the eclipse.ini file. I successfully have used these settings:

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx2048m
```

Good luck with your development!